# Windows 7 Basic theme on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

The Windows 8 setup window uses Windows 7's Basic theme; is there any way to unlock/activate it (not sure if I'm using the right word, but you should get the drift) once it is installed?

Answer (score 4):

There is an "Aero Lite" theme that is all there except for one file that lets it show up in the theme selection dialog. Re-creating that file (aerolite.theme) will let it be selected and used.

Under  C:\Windows\Resources open Themes. Copy the aero.theme file, paste in onto the desktop and rename it aerolite.theme. Open it in notepad. Change two things in the file: under [Theme] `DisplayName=Aero Lite` and under [Visual Styles] `Path=%ResourceDir%\Themes\Aero\Aerolite.msstyles`. Save the file back to the main Themes folder.

Now when you do Desktop Personalization there should be an Aero Lite theme listed.

Answer (score 3):

This is useful:

Open a Command Prompt window and do the following command:

```
Rundll32 dwmApi #102
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party themes which offer the Win7 Basic Look in Windows 8. Before using it you must patch the uxtheme files or use UxStyle.

[image: Windows 7 like Basic Theme for Windows 8]

http://shikharev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-Basic-Style-v2-En-Ru-354831133

Answer (score 0):

Well you can but only one window or some weird stuff.

1. Notice the Windows 7 Basic Theme on System Restore.
2. Open a game (osu! or even Bad Piggies). They only work. Fullscreen them then windowed them.

Answer (score 0):

Download PSTools and extract it and do these commands in admin cmd:

taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F

pssuspend.exe winlogon.exe

taskkill /IM dwm.exe /F

And for explorer.exe to be running while dwm.exe is not running, do this command: c:\windows\explorer.exe

For start menu use Startisback (trial, full or cracked, whatever) or Classic Shell

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: First, doing taskkill /IM dwm.exe /F and not doing pssuspend.exe winlogon.exe will not work. But if you do type taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F and taskkill /IM dwm.exe /F and taskkill /IM dwm.exe will give you the Basic Theme, Also, It works on Windows 10.